# CheckBox Preference Activity how to start and stop service from Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, checkbox, broadcastreceiver, android-service, boot

In my app, I have two buttons to start and stop a service via a receiver class in the manifest along with Package Manager,this Works Fine.

What I would like, is to give the user a preference activity to start the same service with(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)).

I can get the service to start with(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)),but the user has no choice since I have no preference activity.

I know nothing! about preferences other than creating the checkbox in xml  for the preference.

What I need is for the boot receiver to know the state of preference checkbox(true or false) and start the service on boot complete.!

Thank you for any help you can give.

```
enter code here

This is my xml for the preference
<PreferenceScreen
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference

android:key="(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))"
android:defaultValue="false"  
android:id="@+id/checkBox1" 
Preference" />
```

Comment: After much trial and error I have 98% of the code working. My focus has changed to last 2% which is a new question.

Comment: This question has been answered by myself through research and documentation which was not much available.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered by myself through research and documentation which was not much available.It seems that the Package Manger, pending intents and receivers were most of the needs to accomplish the task. Again thanks to anyone who showed interest.